# the usage of dies instead of died

Tags: meaning-in-context, headlinese, obituaries

https://en-maktoob.news.yahoo.com/king-abdullah-bin-abdulaziz-al-saud/

Saudi King Abdullah dies aged 90

I can't understand why in the above sentence there is "dies" instead of "died".

about that event,  bbc world news television, uses "dies" instead of "died" too. why?

Comment: Maybe he is using a die :')

Comment: Because they said so! This is the norm of reporting a piece of news.

Comment: Headlines often employ present tense to announce 'hot news'. It takes fewer characters than what is meant, which is a present perfect: "Saudi King Abdullah **has died**".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as historical present, dramatic present or narrative present. It is the use of the present tense to describe a past event, usually for dramatic emphasis; it makes it seem more real. It's very common in headlines and new stories, especially for deaths.

> Saudi King Abdullah dies aged 90

Could also have been stated as:

> Saudi King Abdullah dead age 90

or

> Saudi King Abdullah has died at age 90

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a headline. Headlines and titles are not complete sentences and are often not grammatically correct. They're trying to get an idea across in as few words as possible.

Headlines often use present tense for something which happened very recently, perhaps because the idea of "news" is that readers want to know what is happening "now". If it was a full sentence, you might write, "King Abdullah died last Thursday at the age of 90." But when you're trying to be concise for a headline, and the death was very recent, like today or yesterday, you just say "King Abdullah dies". In this case, they apparently thought his age at death was important, so they tack on the "Age 90".

Answer (score 1):

Saudi King Abdullah dies aged 90.

Present simple is also used to express a recent past event.  You cannot use it in your colloquial or formal English. It's typical journalese used in news headlines.